# how do i turn a cgpoint into a cgrect or how can i set a calayer's center?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, core-graphics, calayer, cgpoint

i want to align my CALayer to be centered around a point that i get, but im not really that familiar with calayers, dont think they have a center property, ive had some luck with setting the whole frame but i only am given a point to do my positioning. any ideas on either how to get the  rect from a point or better yet set the layers center?

thanks

Nick

Comment: ok im dumb, there is a position property on calayer that takes a cgpoint as an argument. hope this helps someone at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `position` property. It depends on the `anchorPoint` property which defines where the it lies w.r.t to the frame. By default, `anchorPoint` is at the center of the frame and so `position` can be treated as the center of the frame. Unless you change the `anchorPoint`, you can use the `position` property. To be sure, read both of them in the documentation.